# Rails Template::Error (stack level too deep) -- but controller works, and json renders fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Now here's a puzzle... (yes there are questions which match my keywords - but not my situation, it would seem...)

Got a very simple rails app. Only 'index' action in controller, which either returns all models from the DB, or applies filtering based on GET query params (not via ORM).

First two params are fine, third one's driving me crazy. That one is using a 3rd-party gem (calculating geo-distance from the point represented by the model to the point passed in a query). Code works fine in console, and on the server in the controller, and if I render json. But, when trying to render html, the view dies with:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 959ms

ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep):
  sugar-high (0.4.6.4) lib/sugar-high/string.rb:8
```

incidentally, sugar-high is a dependency of geo-distance gem that I'm using, but I don't see the connection -- all the calculations are happening in the controller, and it works with json rendering... why does rendering the html view breaks?

You can see view code here, it's dumb and harmless - just goes through the list of models and renders each one inside a 'li', no other processing:
https://github.com/alexakarpov/earthquakes/blob/master/app/views/earthquakes/index.html.erb

Controller is here:

https://github.com/alexakarpov/earthquakes/blob/master/app/controllers/earthquakes_controller.rb#L27

and the lines of interest are:

```
 near = params[:near]
    if near

      lat, long = near.split(',')
      @near_param = [lat, long]

      @quakes.keep_if { |q|
        dist = GeoDistance::Haversine.geo_distance(lat, long, q.latitude, q.longtitude).miles
        dist <= 5
      }
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @quakes }
    end
  end
```

**'But wait, there's more!'** As soon as I get the error, no other requests for html will work -- even without the 'bad' parameter. At the same time, all json requests keep getting rendered, with or without the 'bad' parameter. So, obviously, the 'view' gets, um... poisoned? Or not the view, but template engine.. or whatever, I'm too new to Rails to get proper names...

Comment: Can you post more of your stack trace?

Comment: All I see in the rails server log is the line I've posted above. Give me a minute, I'll educate myself on how to ask Rails for a more verbose level of logging while in development env...

Comment: Hm... adding "config.log_level = :debug" to development.rb didn't change the amount of detail in my server logs...

Comment: On the in-browser error page there should be links to toggle between the application trace, full trace, etc.

Comment: ah, no, not in this case. I know what you're talking about - but I don't get any of that rendered, because whatever would render all that information dies. I only get this line (from WEBRick itself, I imagine): "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Comment: I cloned your app and ran `rake save_quakes`, but I've been unable to reproduce the problem (on Ruby 1.9.3), so you might be looking for something in your local environment. Does this happen every time you make an html request, or just for certain queries? Do have access to a server or virtual machine you can try it on? Otherwise, I would start digging to see what's calling `String.concat`, which is a core method overridden by the `sugar-high` gem (tsk!). Since it's a core method, I would guess ActionView uses it all over the place.

Comment: oh wow, didn't expect that level of involvement! Thanks a lot. I've only tried it on my linux desktop, and now trying to run everything on my Mac to compare....

Comment: mmyeah, on Mac it's even more mysterious. It dies with this: `Illegal instruction: 4` in the log...